# Dynamically adding classes to a specific instance of another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a specific instance of another class, while modifying the name of the class. This is the code i have:

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
            $('.formEntry')[i].addClass("form" + i);
    }
```

This is the code before the function is ran:

```
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
```

and this is the desired output.

```
<fieldset class = "formEntry form1"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry form2"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry form3"></fieldset>
```

Please help!

Comment: Jayesh's answer is fine, so I won't post another response, but if you're curious, your method doesn't work because `$('.formEntry')[i]` returns the native DOM element, which doesn't have an addClass function. You could either do `$('.formEntry').eq(i)` or `$($('.formEntry')[i])` to get the proper jQuery object that you can call addClass on. (the former is probably better)

Comment: @MatisLepik Oh I see now. Thanks for clarifying; been stuck on this for a while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` for loop through all elements and add class using `.addClass()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".formEntry").each(function(i) {
       $(this).addClass("form" + (i+1));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `each`. `addClass` takes function as well.

```
$('formEntry').addClass(function(i) { return 'form' + (i+1) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for add class dynamically in loop...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
jQuery('.formEntry').each(function(){
  
jQuery(this).addClass('form'+i);
  i++;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
<fieldset class = "formEntry"></fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice() :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
 $('.formEntry').slice(i,(i + 1)).addClass("form" + i);
}
```

[API JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)